# Network error downloading files on OSX

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos

I have a site with a list of photos. The user has the option to download each of the photos. The download just writes the result to the output stream.

Here's the code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DownloadPhotoAsset(string assetId)
{
    var photoAsset = GetPhotoAsset(assetId);

    Stream stream = null;
    int bytesToRead = 10000;
    byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest fileReq =
            (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(photoAsset.FileAbsoluteUrl);
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

        if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

        stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();

        var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                       "attachment; filename=\"" + 
                           Path.GetFileName(photoAsset.FileAbsoluteUrl) + "\"");
        resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

        int length;
        do
        {
            // verify that the client is connected.
            if (resp.IsClientConnected)
            {
                // read data into the buffer and write it out
                // to the response's output stream
                length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                resp.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                // flush the data and clear the buffer
                resp.Flush();
                buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
            }
            else
                length = -1; // cancel the download if client has disconnected
        } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close(); // close the input stream
    }
}
```

This works fine in every browser on Windows, but I get network connection issues on Macs.

- In Safari, the download stops after a second and says "The network connection was lost"
- In Chrome, the error says "Failed - Network Error"
- In Firefox, the error says "Download Error - image.jpeg.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read"

I've checked on two different Macs with OSX 10.7.4 and and OSX 10.8.3

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: are the macs on different networks?

Comment: @DanielA.White - yes they are. I've also tested on Windows machines on different networks, and the download works fine.

Comment: have you tested the windows machines on the same network as the macs?

Comment: @DanielA.White - yes, they work fine.